# Efficiently get shadow prices in scipy linprog

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I have a huge linprog problem of almost 1k variables and restrictions.
I can calculate the solution with `scipy.optimize.linprog(method='simplex')` but I need shadow prices (or opportunity costs) of ~100 inequalities.

I'm able to calculate them by adding 1 to the right side of the inequality and then solving that problem. Then I get the shadow price substracting the objective functions values for both solutions: `shadow_price_i = f_max_original - f_max_i`. Then repeat 100 times. This method works but it's painfully slow (1h).

Is there something I can do to obtain shadow prices quicker? Maybe some trick or functionality I'm missing...

Comment: Sorry. Basically every LP solver returns duals. Scipy linprog seems to be the exception.

Comment: I switched to `cvxpy` and I get my duals in 0.2s, a huge improvement over scipy version (1 solution took over 60secs). I also did a feature request in the github of scipy.

Comment: Excellent. The linprog simplex solver is a dense solver (not exploiting sparsity in the model). So for all but the smallest problems, it is not really competitive.

Comment: @J63 If you did not use a custom-setup (GLPK, Cbc), you are now 
 (cvxpy) using an interior-point method (for the more general problem SOCP). Using pulp (which brings Clp/Cbc) or some alternative simplex-solver directly, i'm sure, that 0.2 is easily beaten (those IPMs also do none / very basic preprocessing), maybe even by scipy's IPM. But make sure you are right about your assumptions: basic-solution vs. non-basic solution.

Comment: @sascha yes I know I'm now using an IPM. On the other hand, scypy's IPM says that my problem is infeasible (in more than 0.2 though... Maybe it's bugged?). 0.2s is good enough for me and the formulation of cxvpy took me 3 lines to translate from the scipy one, I'll check pulp whenever I have a new problem. I don't get what you mean on the last part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve the dual problem and that will give you all the shadow prices with just one more call to `linprog`. Here is an example for a standard LP problem:

```py
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np

c = np.array([400, 200, 250])     # negative of objective function
b = np.array([1000, 300, 625])    # constraint bounds
A = np.array([[3, 1, 1.5],
              [0.8, 0.2, 0.3],
              [1, 1, 1]])        # constraints
x1_bnds = (0, None)     # bounds on x1
x2_bnds = (0, None)     # bounds on x2
x3_bnds = (0, None)     # bounds on x3
result = opt.linprog(-c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(x1_bnds, x2_bnds, x3_bnds))

dual_c = b
dual_b = -1.0 * c
dual_A = -1.0 * np.transpose(A)
result = opt.linprog(dual_c, A_ub=dual_A, b_ub=dual_b,
                     bounds=(x1_bnds, x2_bnds, x3_bnds))
```